# java option Heap dump on out of memory

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments, jvm-hotspot, jvm-crash

In Hotspot JVM 1.4.2, I used the option `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` and it says unknown option. How do I get Heap Dump in this JVM. (I cannot migrate to JVM 6 as its a legacy application running here since years).

Comment: BTW Java 6 is end of life'd. I wouldn't use Java 6 either if you can help it.

Comment: When Java 8 is released sometime this year, Java 7 will be end of life'd two years after that.

Comment: OMG, it's 2004 again. I can go through highschool again :D . Jokes aside: if that option is not in that version of JVM, there's nothing you can do but upgrade. Trust me: you can. You always can. The question is: should you ? Answer: hell yeah ! It's not that big of a challenge or a huge financial hole. Running such an old and dated system is just wrong. And irresponsible. If your company learns this the hard way, it's gonna hurt. A lot.

Comment: Which version of 1.4.2 are you using?

Comment: Find a new job. Any company still running 1.4.2 has obvious critical management issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JVM Options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) state that Heap Dump option was introduced in *Java 1.4.2 update 12*. Make sure you have a same or higher update of 1.4.2.

> Dump heap to file when `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` is thrown.
>   Manageable. (Introduced in 1.4.2 update 12, 5.0 update 7.)

Comment: So there is no way I can get the heap dump in this version ?

Comment: I am afraid that support for this flag is not available. Even http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/exactoptions-jsp-141536.html does not have similar flag. You may have to make a minor update.

Comment: @user2531191 You can get this with 1.4.2, you just need to update the JVM to a newer update.  i.e. there should be any reason you can't do this if you are limited to 1.4.2.

Comment: @PeterLawrey yeah actually this system is running more than a decade (since late 90s). Now its client base has increased manifold and the system shows errors as a result. Why we cannot change the production environment is - It will take a long time to approve as many parties approval needed, and they are not actually willing to make any change.

Comment: @user2531191 Instead of changing the entire client base, you could use version 1.4.2 update 30 to diagnose a specific problem, or recommend to clients which would benefit from a heap dump which version to use instead.  This means you end up supporting two updates but if they are updates of the same version this shouldn't be a big deal.